# getchar eating first character from input

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that checks whether parenthesis are balanced. You enter n number of strings to check and it goes to the function below. The first pass works, but when I test on the second string it eats the first character and says it's not balanced when it is. Then it works again on the third try. I can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
struct Stack* pStack = (Stack*) hStack;
Boolean result = FALSE;
char c, left;

c = getchar();
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
{
  if (c == '{' || c == '(' || c == '[')
  {
    push(pStack, c);
  }
  if (c == '}' || c == ')' || c == ']')
  {
    if(isEmpty(hStack)==TRUE)
    {
      result = FALSE;
      return result;
    }
    else
    {
      left = pop(pStack);
      printf("left: %c, c: %c\n", left, c);
      if ( c == '}' && left == '{') {
        result = TRUE;
      }
      else if (c == ')' && left == '(') {  
        result = TRUE;
      }
      else if (c == ']' && left == '[') {
        result = TRUE;
      }
      else {
        result = FALSE;
      }   
    }
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: There are two `getchar()` one before loop and one inside while loop condition.  first `c` overwritten by one which is inside loop condition. This `c = getchar();` before loop doesn't make any sense, remove it.

Comment: Note `getchar();` returns type `int`.  Best to use `int c; ... c=getchar()` for correct functionality.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)